# Is there a way to set a branch always rebased from another branch?

Tags: git

So I have a branch called `branchA` which diverged from branch `develop`

```
develop
   └ branchA
```

After someone pushed into the `develop` branch, I'd like the `branchA` also have the updates.

```
develop - develop(HEAD)
   └ branchA
```

So I did `git rebase develop` :

```
develop - develop(HEAD)
             └ branchA
```

This works fine. But is there a setting that makes `branchA` always rebased from `develop`?

So I can immediately have the updated contents after someone has pushed into the `develop` branch?

Comment: There is no such setting. You can add some automated scripts that rebase, but eventually one of those will end up with a merge conflict and you're going to dislike it more than you like having it. Get into the habit of doing it when needed.

Comment: Well, I thought there's a way to automate this procedure. Guess it will be unsafe since git doesn't know how to handle conflicts automatically :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will solve your issue, but you could set up a post-checkout hook that will do the rebase every time you check out branchA
In short:
add a file called post-checkout in your .git hooks folder:

```
.git/hooks/post-checkout
```

make the file executable (chmod +x) and in it you can add an if statement (checking that you are on branchA as a condition for rebasing)

You can check out the git hooks documentation here for more information:
https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, haven't used hooks before. I will look into that.